# For website development, is there an advantage to using Private vs Public repositories?

Tags: html, git, repository

I'm completely new to Git, and one question I have that I cannot seem to find an answer to is this: when building a website is there any advantage to using private repositories vs public? I'm not referring to developing web-apps or other proprietary information so-to-speak, just basic web development. For example I would like to learn to use git (github) by updating our current website. Since source code is viewable to all, what advantages would be gained by using a private repository?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a HTML/CSS/JS-only website, there's not a huge difference, as you're correct that it's all visible to anyone browsing the site. A private repository is going to be more of an issue if you've got server-side code (PHP, Ruby, etc.)

Comment: That's really up to you/your organization to decide. Do you care if people have access to all of your source code? Everyone's circumstances are a bit too different to give a general answer i think. Be aware of any potential licensing issues if you do have your repository open to the public.

Comment: GIT is for source code control.  You can use it for other types of files, but is was designed for source code.  If you want to store HTML you can.  If you are working with other people and there is no proprietary information you want to keep secret in your repository than you can use a public or private GIR repository.  Public repositories are often free.  If you want to keep what is in your repository a secret you likely want to use a private repository.  Private repositories often cost money.  BTW, public repositories can usually be updated by anyone.

Comment: The server side code usually is private and maybe should be protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just developing in html/css/javascript(frontend), that is all viewable to the client. If you start to use server side scripting, (i.e PHP) you may have more sensitive data that you do not want public. You can also use git as a local repository and not have anything on github. That will handle source control and will all be kept local to the machine it is on. If you are developing on a server that other people use, they can also have access to edit that local repository.

Here is a good page for how to set up a [local repository.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/)